# Expo on iOS is constantly refreshing my React Native app on MacOS, caused by Dropbox / iCloud

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, dropbox, expo

I'm building a simple React Native app and using the Expo iOS app to run it. But Expo is constantly refreshing my app, making it unusable / untestable. It refreshes every few seconds, sometimes multiple times a second, when I haven't changed anything. The only times when there is enough of a break between refreshes for me to test out the app is when, in my terminal, the app decides to rebuild (Again, nothing changed) and takes a few seconds to rebuild the bundle.

I set up the app using `create-react-native-app` and run it with `npm start` -- I've changed nothing else, besides adding a few components.

I've tried quitting my IDE (Sublime) and changing to a stronger wifi network.

I'm developing on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 and running on an iPhone 6S.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It turns out this happened because my app's code was stored inside a Dropbox folder. (The same applies to iCloud backups.)

I guess that Dropbox's / iCloud's syncing interferes with watchman or other Expo / React Native internals.

I solved the problem by removing the app's directory from my Dropbox folder.

Comment: Same problem with iCloud. Took me hours before I found the solution here. Thanks!

Comment: For iCloud backups, waiting until the backup is close to complete solves the problem as well.

Comment: You can also just pause Dropbox syncing, then re-enable when you are done with development, which I chose to do in order to keep my project with all my other dev work on Dropbox.

Answer (score 3):

For all the people who have this problem on Mac because of iCloud downloading the folder, if you rename a folder to "tmp" then iCloud will skip it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) installed?

The React Native packager (["metro bundler"](https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler)) watches your app directory for changes and reloads the app whenever a file is changed in the directory, oddly this doesn't cause any problems for me when I use Dropbox, though.

Comment: I had `watchman` as a local dep and also tried it with and without watchman as a global dep (`npm install -g watchman`). I didn't try installing watchman with brew, though.

Comment: It only seems to happen on a Dropbox folder while the files in the RN app folder are actively syncing to Dropbox.  If you pause syncing the behavior stops.  If you resume syncing the behavior starts again.